# How to check if two given line segments intersect

Tags: algorithms

I was trying to understand convex hull problem..i came across a method to check intersection of line segment. Suppose the points are $p_1, q_1$ and $p_2, q_2$. One case says that the line segments will intersect if

> - $(p1,q1,p2)$ and $(p1,q1,q2)$ have different
>     orientations and
> - $(p2,q2,p1)$ and $(p2,q2,q1)$ have different
>     orientations

I am not able to understand the meaning of orientation? How can different orientations lets us decide that the segment will intersect? Can some one explain it, please?

I am reading it from [here](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~pat/52233/slides/Geometry1x1.pdf) 8th page

Comment: What does the notation $(a,b,c)$ mean in this context?

Comment: i didn't understand what u are asking??

Comment: Orientation is defined on p.5. It is not clear to me why this approach is any better than just computing the intersections...

Comment: but how does orientation helps in deciding if two line segments intersect??

Comment: @copper.hat I'm guessing it is slightly faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can different orientations lets us decide that the segment will intersect?

If $p_1$, $q_1$, and $x$ are points in the plane, the "orientation" of $(p_1, q_1, x)$ is *counterclockwise* if $x$ lies in the open half-plane to the *left* of the segment $p_1q_1$, and is *clockwise* if $x$ lies in the *right* half-plane, see page 5 of the PDF file you linked. The first of the conditions

> - $(p_1,q_1,p_2)$ and $(p_1,q_1,q_2)$ have different orientations and
> - $(p_2,q_2,p_1)$ and $(p_2,q_2,q_1)$ have different orientations

expresses the fact that $p_2$ and $q_2$ lie "on opposite sides" of the segment $p_1q_1$ (i.e., in different open half planes). Similarly, the second condition says $p_1$ and $q_1$ lie "on opposite sides" of the segment $p_2q_2$. If both conditions hold, then each segment crosses the line defined by the other segment, which means the *segments* intersect.

If that doesn't clarify, it may help (psychologically, if not logically) to draw a couple of segments that do not cross, and to convince yourself that at least one segment lies entirely within one of the open half-planes defined by the other segment.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a\mid b)$ and $(c\mid d)$ are endpoints of one segment, and
if $(e\mid f)$ and $(g\mid h)$ are endpoints of the other, and
if $(i\mid j)$ is the intersection of the two lines that contain the segments,
then the two segments intersect
if $((a\leqslant i \leqslant c) \vee (a\geqslant i \geqslant c))\wedge$
$((b \leqslant j \leqslant d) \vee (b \geqslant j \geqslant d)) \wedge$
$((e \leqslant i \leqslant g) \vee (e \geqslant i \geqslant g)) \wedge$
$((f \leqslant j \leqslant h)\vee(f \geqslant j \geqslant h))$.