# What is cross product in $2D$ space and how does it help detect if $2$ line segments intersect?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, vectors, computational-geometry

I am having to solve a problem from computational geometry which involves finding out if $2$ given line segments intersect.

More about the problem I am trying to solve over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3707481/407302) if anyone is interested.

Now I keep coming across the following calculation:

```
(v1.X*v2.Y) - (v1.Y*v2.X)
```

It is suppose to be the [vector cross product in 2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/243984/7134737).

Now I have a couple of questions:

1. What is the vector cross product in $2D$ ? Its not even defined there, so what is going on ?
2. If the cross product is used so extensively why is it called as "mathematical hack" ? Everyone seems to be expected to know about it.
3. **How does it help when finding out if $2$ lines intersect or not ?** What does it have to do with orientation like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/696959/407302).

**I want to know how I can use this calculation to find out if $2$ lines intersect. What is the intuition behind it ?**

How does it help ?

Thanks.

Comment: In three dimensions this 'cross product' is a vector; in two dimensions it's just a number. In fact, it's the determinant of the 2x2 matrix you get from considering v1 and v2 as a basis. Thinking of it as the core of a transformation of basis _might_ (depending on your linear algebra knowledge) be the most intuitive explanation for its role, though there are still a few steps to get there.

Answer (score 2):

The "vector cross product in 2D" is neither a product (in the strict sense), nor a "vector", nor is it really in 2D. Other than that, it's well named. :(

The ordinary cross product takes a pair of nonzero vectors in 3-space, $u$ and $v$, and produces a new vector $w = u \times v$ whose length is the area of the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $v$ (hence the length may be zero), and whose direction (if $w$ is nonzero) is perpendicular to $u$ and $v$, and has the property that $u, v, w$ (in that order) form a right-hand-oriented basis of 3-space.

If you have a pair of vectors $u$ adn $v$ in the plane, you can append a $0$ to each one, so if $u = (a, b)$, you get $U = (a, b, 0)$, and similarly for $v$. Then $W = U \times V$ is a vector in 3-space perpendicular to both (but possibly zero!). Well, perpendicular to both means that it must have the form
$$
W = (0, 0, z)
$$
and the
expression you've written down is exactly the formula for that $z$ component. That means that if $u, v$ is a positively-oriented basis for the plane, then the "2D cross product" will be positive; if it's negatively oriented, the "product" will be negative. And if it's zero, then one of the vectors $u$ adn $v$ is a multiple of the other.

As for testing for intersection of segments, probably your best bet is to look for papers by Thomas Akenine-Moller, who has pretty much written the be-all and end-all of such papers. There's no reason to rehash the contents here.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the papers of Moller that you are referring to ? I could not find what you are referring to.

Comment: How is the result of a 2D "cross product" a scalar when the result of a 3D cross product is another 3D vector? Why the inconsistency ?

Comment: The thing that you have called the "2d cross product" of $u$ and $v$ is the third coordinate of the cross product of the extended vectors $U$ and $V$. This third coordinate is the only one that's nonzero, so while you could write down $(0,0,z)$, it's easier to just write down $z$. Most "products" of two things produce another "thing" (the product of two integers is an integer; the cross product of two 3-vectors is a 3-vector; the "product" in any group or ring produces a new element of the group or ring). There are exceptions: "inner products" take pairs of vectors to numbers, etc.

Comment: The paper by Tomas that I was thinking of was this one https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10867651.1997.10487472?src=recsys, which probably says as much about segment-segment testing as most people would want. Surely forward and backward chasing this reference will find you more.

Answer (score 0):

There exists another product of vectors called the wedge product. The wedge product of two vectors creates a 2-dimensional directed/oriented object called a bivector, and the wedge product of a $m$-dimensional and a $n$-dimensional  directed object is a $m+n$-dimensional directed object. These higher dimensional directed objects are usually called $k$-vectors. The wedge product is quite useful, as it could be used to find the area/volume of parallelograms and parallelopipeds (and higher-dimensional hyperparallelopipeds) bounded by the given vectors, for example.

For each $k$-vector in $n$-dimensional space, with $k \leq n$, there exists a dual object, a $(n - k)$-vector that is perpendicular to the original $k$-vector with the same magnitude. In 3 dimensions, the dual of a bivector yields a vector with the same magnitude perpendicular to the bivector, while in 2 dimensions, the dual of a bivector yields a scalar with the same magnitude (scalars are trivially perpendicular to higher-dimensional objects).

1. In any dimension, the cross product of two vectors can be defined as the dual of the wedge product of two vectors.
2. It is for the above reason that the cross product is called a hack, because the wedge product is more fundamental in linear algebra and geometry than the cross product. But due to historical reasons from fundamental 19th century physics, Gibb's vector algebra eventually became dominant in the study of electromagnetism, and so physicists and mathematicians use the cross product instead of the wedge product.
3. Two vectors are parallel if the wedge product (and consequently the cross product) of the two vectors is zero. The given formula calculates the magnitude of the wedge product of two vectors in two dimensions. In two dimensions, any two distinct lines lie on the same plane, and so if the wedge product of two vectors defining the two lines are zero, then the two lines are parallel; otherwise, they intersect.

See also:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Motivating_examples

Comment: Could you explain why - "In two dimensions, any two distinct lines lie on the same plane, and so if the wedge product of two vectors defining the two lines are zero, then the two lines are parallel; otherwise, they intersect."

Comment: Because that's an axiom in Euclidean geometry. Parallel lines do not intersect.